# Origin of the modern definition of the tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, math-history, tensor-products

Due to whom is the modern (i.e. via its universal property) definition of the tensor product, and in which article was it communicated?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My recollection agrees with Mariano. Here's an except from Weibel's [History of homological algebra](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/0245/)
[image]

and from p. 172 of Mac Lane's *Homology*
[image]

and from Whitney's *Collected Papers* v. 1
[image]

Comment: what is the reference B43 which is quoted in the weibel's book?

Comment: @PtF R. Baer, *Erwiterung von Gruppen und ihren Isomorphismen,* Math. Zeit. 38 (1934), 375-416. Note that I added a link to an online source of Weibel's paper.

Comment: There is no [B43] reference in Weibel's paper: it is a typo in Weibel's paper and should be [B42].  The Baer paper is [B34], which is from 1934 and thus precedes the abstract definition of tensor products by Whitney (for abelian groups).  The reference [B42] is Chapter 2 of Bourbaki's Algebre.

Answer (score 11):

The article

> Whitney, Hassler. Tensor products of Abelian groups. Duke Mathematical Journal 4 (1938), no. 3, 495--528. [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/sim_duke-mathematical-journal_1938_4_0/page/495/mode/1up)

is usually credited as the original source.

Very soon after that, Bourbaki crystallized the modern definition.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find that paper free online, which is sad.

Comment: If someone wants a copy of Whitney's paper I can send it by mail. You can contact me at my first.lastname at gmail.com

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ask and you shall receive